# can't modification url pagination laravel

Tags: php, laravel

call pagination on index

```
public function index(){  

    $image = DB::table('images')
        ->join('experiences', 'experiences.id', '=', 'images.experience_id')
        ->select('experiences.id','main_image', 'images.status', 'title')
        ->where('main_image','!=',null)
        ->get();

    $image2 = DB::table('images')
        ->join('parks', 'parks.id', '=', 'images.park_id')
        ->where('images','!=',null)
        ->where('images','!=','')
        ->select('parks.id','images as main_image', 'images.status', DB::raw('null as title'))->get();

    $merged = $image->merge($image2);
    $data = $merged->all();

    $query = $this->paginate($data);

    // dd($query->links());  is show http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=1"

}
```

**and this my function pagination on controller**

```
public function paginate($items, $perPage = 10, $page = null, $options = [])
{
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
    return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}
```

i tried 
change url http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=1 to http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/image?page=1
but still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to modify the path with `->setPath($path)` method

```
$query = $this->paginate($data)->setPath('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/image'); //use route() instead of string
```